# Average marks from list

Tags: bash, awk

Sorry if I don't write good, it's my first post.

I have a list in one file with the name, id, marks etc of students (see below):

And I want to calculate the average mark in another file, but I don't know how to take only the marks and write the average in another file.

Thanks;

```sh
#name surname student_index_number course_group_id lecturer_id list_of_marks
athos musketeer 1 1 1 3,4,5,3.5
porthos musketeer 2 1 1 2,5,3.5
aramis musketeer 3 2 2 2,1,4,5
```

```sh
while read line; do
    echo "$line" | cut -f 6 -d ' '
done<main_list
```

Comment: What does the desired output look like? What was wrong with your attempt?

Comment: I want to write in average text file, the name of the student and his average mark like:
athos 3.75

Comment: @oguzismail I would like to get from main_list the name and marks so the output would be like:
athos 3.75
porthos 2.25

Comment: @oguzismail yes, it was an example, I need to write all names with their marks

Comment: Oh yes, thank you all @oguzismail

Comment: I meant that you should [edit] your question with the expected output and what didn't work with your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR>1{n=split($NF,a,",");for(i=1;i<=n;i++){s+=a[i]} ;print $1,s/n;s=0}' input
athos 3.875
porthos 3.5
aramis 3
```

For all the lines except header(`NR>1` will filter out header) , pick up the last column  and split into smaller numbers by comma. Using `for loop` sum the value of all the marks and then divid by the total subject number.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (untested)

```
awk '{ n = split($6, a, ","); total=0; for (v in a) total += a[v]; print total / n }' main_list
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure BASH solution, could you please try following once.

```
while read first second third fourth fifth sixth
do
  if [[ "$first" =~ (^#) ]]
  then
      continue
  fi
  count="${sixth//[^,]}"    
  val=$(echo "(${#count}+1)" |  bc)
  echo "scale=2; (${sixth//,/+})/$val" | bc
done < "Input_file"
```

Comment: @GarciSan, could you please let me know  if this answer helped you?